# Viceversa in mysql query clause

Tags: mysql

I want to select record based on two conditional

```
  SELECT *
  FROM record
  WHERE FromPersonID in (1,2) AND
  ToPersonID in (1,2)
```

However this query can give me a record like this:

```
 +--------+----------------+----------------
 |  id    |  FromPersonID  |   ToPersonID |
 +--------+----------------+----------------
     1             1              2
     2             1              1
     3             2              2
     4             2              1
     5             1              2
```

In the id of 2 and 3, the record has the same value in FromPersonID and ToPersonID

What I want is that it will only check the viceversa between the two field.

Can any body help to acchieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get

```
     2             1              1
     3             2              2


SELECT *
  FROM record
  WHERE FromPersonID in (1,2) AND
  ToPersonID in (1,2) and FromPersonID=ToPersonID;
```

else if you want to get RECORDS WHICH HAVE DIFFERENT VALUE FOR THOSE TWO COLUMNS

```
SELECT *
      FROM record
      WHERE FromPersonID in (1,2) AND
      ToPersonID in (1,2) and FromPersonID!=ToPersonID;



SELECT * FROM TT;
+------+--------------+------------+
| ID   | FromPersonID | TOPERSONID |
+------+--------------+------------+
|    1 |            1 |          2 |
|    2 |            1 |          1 |
|    3 |            2 |          2 |
|    4 |            2 |          1 |
|    5 |            1 |          2 |
+------+--------------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

 SELECT *       FROM TT       WHERE FromPersonID in (1,2) AND  TOPERSONID in (1,2) and FromPersonID!=TOPERSONID;
+------+--------------+------------+
| ID   | FromPersonID | TOPERSONID |
+------+--------------+------------+
|    1 |            1 |          2 |
|    4 |            2 |          1 |
|    5 |            1 |          2 |
+------+--------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: The second part is what I want, but the query doesn't achieve what I want. You can test it.

Comment: i have already tested it updated sample data set please check its working

Comment: Weird, in my record the `FromPersonID` will be always 1 AND `TOPERSONID` will be always 2, no viceversa record.

Comment: @al_kasih_empatix can you paste your query as a comment

Comment: Ok, I think the problem comes from the record of my table. It should achieve what I want if the viceversa record is exist. Thanks.